# A do-it-yourself user registration system

Tags: users

I would like to create an Ubuntu server, where I am the root user, and non-root users can register on their own (e.g. via a web-interface or another way) - without me having to run "adduser" for each one.

A search for "Ubuntu user management" or "Ubuntu user management system" returned only explanations about how the root user can manually manage the users in their system. Is there a way to let users create new accounts on their own?

Comment: Haven't tried it yet but it's on my long term to-do list. You'll want to install LAMP (google that). You'll want to search on "Apache User Management" I believe.

Comment: Just thinking out loud... Root required to add new user, Web server not able to execute root commands... What about creating a bash script running as a daemon reading a text file written by the web server?